# Django model not saving for some reason (after second run of function)

Tags: python, django

I am making a game. For users to be able to move, they need to solve math problems. Up/down/left/right each have problems. At the beginning of the game, 4 math problems are generated. Here is the code for it:

```
def generate_first_4_problems(level, operation, game_object, player_type):

    creator_problems = ['p1up', 'p1right', 'p1down', 'p1left']
    opponent_problems = ['p2up', 'p2right', 'p2down', 'p2left']

    problems = []
    answers = []
    while len(problems) < 4:
        problem = generate_problem(level, operation)
        answer = x(problem).expr()
        if answer not in answers:
            problems.append(problem)
            answers.append(answer)
    print('problems')
    print(problems)
    if player_type == 'creator':
        for i, d in enumerate(creator_problems):
            setattr(game_object, d, problems[i])
            print('creator_problem %s' % d)
            print(getattr(game_object, d))
        game_object.save()
    elif player_type == 'opponent':
        for i, d in enumerate(opponent_problems):
            setattr(game_object, d, problems[i])
            print('opponent_problem %s' % d)
            print(getattr(game_object, d))
        game_object.save()
    game_object.save()
    print('after save')
    print(game_object.p1up)
    return problems
```

This code is run twice for each player (creator and opponent)
also, here is what is printed:

```
problems
['7 + 3', '1 + 4', '10 + 9', '8 - 10']    
creator_problem p1up
7 + 3
creator_problem p1right
1 + 4
creator_problem p1down
10 + 9
creator_problem p1left
8 - 10
after save
7 + 3
{'problem_list': ['7 + 3', '1 + 4', '10 + 9', '8 - 10']}
problems
['2 + 6', '2 + 3', '4 - 8', '0 + 3']
opponent_problem p2up
2 + 6
opponent_problem p2right
2 + 3
opponent_problem p2down
4 - 8
opponent_problem p2left
0 + 3
after save
None
```

code that calls first func:

```
def generate_first_4_problems_game(level, operation, game_object, player_type):
    problem_list = generate_first_4_problems(
        level, operation, game_object, player_type)
    context['problem_list'] = problem_list
```

Can anyone help?

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 119, in run
    consumer(message, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 78, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 42, in inner
    return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/engine/game_consumers.py", line 439, in ws_receive_game
    signals[signal]()
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/engine/game_consumers.py", line 421, in send_answer
    if is_correct_answer(getattr(game, d), int(answer)):
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/engine/game_consumers.py", line 60, in is_correct_answer
    answer = x(problem_string).expr()
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/parsley.py", line 85, in invokeRule
    ret, err = self._grammar.apply(name, *args)
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 462, in apply
    val, err = self._apply(r, ruleName, args)
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 495, in _apply
    [rule(), self.input])
  File "/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py", line 198, in rule_expr
    _G_apply_55, lastError = self._apply(self.rule_expr2, "expr2", [])
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 495, in _apply
    [rule(), self.input])
  File "/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py", line 218, in rule_expr2
    _G_apply_61, lastError = self._apply(self.rule_value, "value", [])
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 495, in _apply
    [rule(), self.input])
  File "/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py", line 62, in rule_value
    _G_or_19, lastError = self._or([_G_or_15, _G_or_17])
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 598, in _or
    ret, err = f()
  File "/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py", line 54, in _G_or_15
    _G_apply_16, lastError = self._apply(self.rule_number, "number", [])
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 495, in _apply
    [rule(), self.input])
  File "/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py", line 17, in rule_number
    _G_consumedby_5, lastError = self.consumedby(_G_consumedby_1)
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 676, in consumedby
    _, e = expr()
  File "/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py", line 14, in _G_consumedby_1
    _G_many1_4, lastError = self.many(_G_many1_2, _G_many1_2())
  File "/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py", line 11, in _G_many1_2
    _G_apply_3, lastError = self._apply(self.rule_digit, "digit", [])
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 495, in _apply
    [rule(), self.input])
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 790, in digit
    x, e = self.rule_anything()
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 813, in rule_anything
    h, p = self.input.head()
  File "/home/michael/projects/gameapollius/apvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py", line 232, in head
    if self.position >= len(self.data):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

relevant func (to traceback)

```
def send_answer(answer, game_object, player_type):

    creator_problems = ['p1up', 'p1right', 'p1down', 'p1left']
    opponent_problems = ['p2up', 'p2right', 'p2down', 'p2left']

    if player_type == 'creator':
        for d in creator_problems:
            print('getattr')
            print(getattr(game, d))
            if is_correct_answer(getattr(game, d), int(answer)):
                context['move_direction'] = d
    elif player_type == 'opponent':
        for d in opponent_problems:
            print('getattr')
            print(getattr(game, d))
            if is_correct_answer(getattr(game, d), int(answer)):
                context['move_direction'] = d
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this method?

Comment: sure, one second

Comment: What I'm looking for is the whole call stack, going back to when the `game_object` is loaded, and ultimately passed in twice.

I mostly reproduced things with some stubbing, and it worked as expected.

As another general note, you could likely put most of this into the Game model itself, unless you were expecting to share some of this problem generation code outside of the model? You wouldn't need to call twice, you'd just go `game_object.generate_problems(level, operation)` and it would generate both creator and opponent problems in one go.

Comment: added traceback and relevant code. and currently I send requests to generate each problem from each client. one request from 'creator' and one from 'opponent'. This is how it should work when there are actually 2 people playing.